# How to access statistics of all running apps on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is possible to develop an app to access all the statistics of other apps? For example, I'd like to know:

1. When the apps are launched
2. How long each particular app is running in the foreground (total combined time)
3. How long each app had been running in the background?

(I've done some research and know it is possible to get all the apps, but are those info mentioned available? Reference: [List of applications running in background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633388/list-of-applications-running-in-background-process) )

Thanks!

Comment: You got the information for OS X platform and your post is tagged with iOS.

Comment: you can use google analytics

Comment: If you want for Mac OS, i can provide you entire applicatin with code... but plz be clear, ios or mac.

Comment: When and How Long are ridiculous queries.  Modern software shouldn't deal with things the OS handles for us invisibly.

Comment: iOS (as written in the question itself) - :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think unless you jailbreak your device, you won't easily have access to the system processes/list of running apps. If you just want to measure your own apps, you can use Google Analytics to get an idea of the usage of the app.

If you want to measure system/other apps you will be out of luck. Especially on end user devices.